# How can I draw the following lines using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I draw the following background image?

[image: Lines using CSS]

Comment: easiest wa would be the usage of a SVG. alternatively canvas or pseudo-elements can do it aswell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

conic-gradient, mask and pseudo element

```css
html:before,
html:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 130%;
  left: -40%;
  bottom: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid green;
  -webkit-mask: conic-gradient(#000, #0000 65%);
}

html:after {
  transform: translate(15%);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Can't we do similar curve only for a section of a page?@temani-afif

Comment: @RuhulAmin apply the pseudo element to that section instead of html